# Difference between miracast and mirrorlink technologies?

Tags: wifi-direct, miracast, mirrorlink

I know that Miracast(peer-to-peer wireless screencasting standard) uses wifi-direct and Mirrorlink doesn't.

Miracast applies to an any two devices(having wifi-direct) where as Mirrorlink applies to car infotainment devices and mobile.

Other then the above mentioned are there any other difference I should know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MirrorLink allows you to use a supporting head unit as a remote terminal for supporting phones. It provides framebuffer replication (like Miracast), but it also provides control events, application selection support (via UPnP), bi-directional audio, and bi-directional data exchange. You can run MirrorLink over WiFi if the devices support, but most devices use USB connectivity.

Answer (score 1):

With Mirrorlink, you can control your phone by touching on sink's screen. Miracast just mirror, you can't do anything else

Answer (score 0):

Mirror Link just mirror! you can't control the phone touching de stereo screen :(